# Setting state in function doesn't trigger a rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I want to make a loading indicator on user login, but for some reason the JSX conditional element does not update:

```
class LoginPage extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      waitingOnLogin: false,
      ...
    }

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this)
  }

  handleLogin (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.state.waitingOnLogin = true
    this.props.userActions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='up'>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleLogin(e)}> ... </form>
        {this.state.waitingOnLogin && <Spinner message='Logging you in'/>} // This does not appear
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Why does the `waitingOnLogin` is being ignored by the JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mutate state directly use `setState`. setState calls for rerender and hence after that your change will reflect but with direct assignment no `rerender` occurs and thus no change is reflected. Also you should always use `setState` to change state

```
handleLogin (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({waitingOnLogin:true});
    this.props.userActions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use `setState` to update the `state` value, never mutate the `state` values directly, Use this:

```
handleLogin (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ waitingOnLogin: true });
    this.props.userActions.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
}
```

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Check the details about [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).